# How do you require angular template html?

Tags: angularjs

When creating custom directives, if you want to put your view/template html in separate files, Angular seems to load the template from a public URL, making an HTTP request for it.

How do you include this template HTML `inline` while keeping it in a separate file?

Comment: can you give and example of this term :-  `How do you include this template HTML inline while keeping it in a separate file?`

Answer (score 2):

With ES6 nothing is impossible:

```
import yourTemplate from 'path/to/file';

// inject $templateProvider in start point of your application

$templateProvider.put('path/to/file', yourTemplate);
```

`$templateProvider` at its own is simple `$cacheFactory` instance, where you can put any html, by any key, that can be used in ng-include or simply used in your directive as shown below:

```
//Directive
import yourTemplate from 'path/to/file';
```

that is used within directive configuration:

```
...,
controller: xxx,
template: yourTemplate,
link: () => { ... }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use directive to fix this

**HTML**

```
<div custom-include url="{{url}}"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('customInclude', ['$http', '$compile', '$timeout', customInclude]);
    function customInclude($http, $compile, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function link($scope, elem, attrs) {
                //if url is not empty
                if (attrs.url) {
                    $http({ method: 'GET', url: attrs.url, cache: true }).then(function (result) {
                        elem.append($compile(angular.element(result.data))($scope));
                        //after sometime we add width and height of modal
                        $timeout(function () {
                            //write your own code
                        }, 1, false);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"inline" in a separate file is contradicting itself.

Since angular is client side code, loading a template that is stored in it's own separate file will always require a http request.

The only way to avoid these requests is to add them inline with your other code, so not in a separate file.